# Clear NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am wanting to store dateArray in internalElement and then clear dateArray so when the for loop starts over I have new data in dateArray. Currently i am trying to use [dateArray clearAllobjects] to delete the data but when i do that it also clears out internalElement. Is there a better way to do this or what am I not getting. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
NSMutableArray *dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    internalElement = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        newDate = object[@"date"];
        if([oldDate isEqual:@""]) {
            NSMutableArray *transactionDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [transactionDetails addObject:object[@"amount"]];
            [transactionDetails addObject:object[@"memo"]];
            [transactionDetails addObject:object[@"category"][@"name"]];
            [dateArray addObject:transactionDetails];

            oldDate = object[@"date"];
        } else if([newDate isEqual:oldDate]) {

            NSMutableArray *transactionDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [transactionDetails addObject:object[@"amount"]];
            [transactionDetails addObject:object[@"memo"]];
            [transactionDetails addObject:object[@"category"][@"name"]];

            oldDate = object[@"date"];
        } else {

            [internalElement setObject:dateArray forKey:oldDate];
            NSLog(@"Date Array%@", internalElement);
            [dateArray removeAllObjects];
            NSLog(@"Date Array%@", internalElement);
            NSMutableArray *transactionDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [transactionDetails addObject:object[@"amount"]];
            [transactionDetails addObject:object[@"memo"]];
            [transactionDetails addObject:object[@"category"][@"name"]];

            [dateArray addObject:transactionDetails];
            //[transactionDetails removeAllObjects];
            oldDate = object[@"date"];

        }

        [internalElement setObject:object[@"date"] forKey:@"date"];
        [internalElement setObject:object[@"amount"] forKey:@"amount"];
        [transactionArray addObject:internalElement];
    }
```

Comment: You can't reuse `internalElement` like you are. Create a new instance each time inside the `for` loop.

Comment: You also seem to be creating the `transactionDetails` array to no purpose; you're allocating it but not using it.

Comment: When you put an object into your array it is just a reference to that object.  If you want to be able to re-use that reference then copy the data before putting it into your array. You can use the copy or mutableCopy methods to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how object pointers work.

Consider the following "real-world" pseudo-code example:

A teacher of a class wants to move a bunch of books from one side of the room to another. She wants to involve all the children, so she devises a scheme where each child will take a handful of books over.

**Your way:**

```
1. The teacher lines up all the children.
2. The teacher brings the first child in line over to her. Let's call him Timmy.
3.   The teacher makes sure Timmy isn't carrying a handful of books.
4.   The teacher gives Timmy a handful of books.
5.   The teacher tells Timmy to stand on her left side.
6. Repeat steps 3-5 once for each member of the class.
```

Since the teacher only ever fetched the child once, it's always poor Timmy.

**The right way:**

```
1. The teacher lines up all the children.
2.   The teacher brings the first child in line over to her.
3.   The teacher makes sure the child isn't carrying a handful of books.
4.   The teacher gives the child a handful of books.
5.   The teacher tells the child to stand on her left side.
6. Repeat steps 2-5 once for each member of the class.
```

**To fix your source, interchange these two lines:**

```
internalElement = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (PFObject *object in objects) {
```

as:

```
for (PFObject *object in objects) {
internalElement = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```